# Destroy pickup object OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, onmousedown

I just released my first indie horror game a few days ago and am in the process of updating it. In my game, the objective is to go around activating several generators in order to restore the power and escape. I want to make my game a bit more realistic, so, I'm adding gasoline canisters that you can use to activate the generators. I need some help creating a script that allows the player to pickup gas canisters and use them to activate the generators. Here's what I have so far:

```
    public class GasCanisters : MonoBehaviour

public GameObject Player;
public GameObject[] GasCanisters;
public AudioClip PickupSound;

void Update()
{
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(PickupSound, transform.position);

  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Gas Canister"))
     GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);
              }
}
```

As you could probably tell, I'm a very basic and bad programmer. But anyhow, I'd really appreciate all the help I could get on this.

Comment: What's the question? At the moment we have a very vague idea of what you are asking :) - is anything not working?

Comment: The only thing that I can notice so far, is that `gameObject` (in last line) is undefined. Maybe you meant `Player` (which should, possibly, start with a lower case letter, since it is *not* a Class constructor, but a variable).

Comment: @hlfrmn gameObject isn't undefined, when you type gameObject in a script in unity it will refer to the gameObject the script is attached to, which is inherited from MonoBehaviour.

Comment: You should probably be comparing if the object you clicked is the canister your are destroying, with your current script if you click on a single gas canister, every object with this script attached will be destroyed.

Comment: why Destroy is called like a method of GameObject, isn't this a static function fro MonoB...

Comment: @Charleh, I need help making the gas canister able to be picked up by the player. Then used as a "key" to activate the generator. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK, there's a lot to do here; first, don't use Update, that runs every frame regardless of whether your player in 1 metre or 200 miles from the canister which wastes a lot of CPU time. Instead use [OnMouseOver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html). Ensure you have a [collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) on your canister then add a script with something like:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
   if(Input.GetButtonDown)
   {
       transform.SetParent(yourPlayersHand.transform);
       transform.localPosition = Vector3.Zero;
       transform.localRotation = Quaterion.Identity;
   }
}
```

This will 'attach' the canister to your players hand. You might want to fiddle with the position & orientation to get it to look right.

Second, you need some way to identify the canister, the easiest way would be to add a [tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html).

Next, add a similar script to the generator to do what you want, something like:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
   if(Input.GetButtonDown)
   {
       if(yourPlayersHand.transform.GetChild(0).tag == "canister")
       {
            // your code for what happens
       }
   }
}
```